# Suppress FxCop warnings on a solution level

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop

I know FxCop permits us to suppress a warning on a local or project level, but is there a way to suppress warnings that are irrelevant to our software on a solution level?

My team's solution literally contains hundreds of projects and it would be a pain to maintain that may suppression files.

Comment: How are you running FxCop?

Answer (score 1):

I think most of what you want can be found in [Using FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429362%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), especially in the sections "Managing FxCop Projects" and "Managing Rules".

Keep in mind that a "FxCop Project" is a set of rules and the only control you have over the rules is enabling or disabling them.

You can keep a FxCop project for the entire company, by leaving the project file where FxCop is installed or have a different FxCop project per solution.

In my company, we do the second by copying the entire FxCop folder into the product folder (one product has typically many MVS solutions) and running it from there. There may be simpler ways, but the folder is only 5 MB, so it doesn't hurt.